# Customised confirmation dialog in a Lightning component

Tags: javascript, lightning, lightning-apps, css

Hi I want to show a confirm dialog as shown

[image]

can the do the same using Lightning CSS.

I know we can use onclick="return confirm('test');" but look and feel of the same is different. How should I achieve this easily using lightning?

Comment: Did you try [Modals](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/modals/) in Lightning Design System?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you trigger an event with a callback function.
Here is a light draft of what u could do.

MyComponent.helper :

```
 mycomponentHelperMethod(component,event)
    var callBack = function (dialogResult) {
          component.set('v.dialogResult',dialogResult);
    };
    var NewEvent = $A.get('e.c:EvtRequestDialog') ;
    NewEvent.setParams({
        'question' : 'TitleOfYourQuestion',
        'answerList' : 'yes','no',
        'callBack': callBack 
    }).fire() ;
}
```

Your create a component MyDialogComponent, who handles this event, and is displayed when receiving it
after the onClickMethod behind a button,

```
doInit(component,event,helper){
    component.set('v.callBack',event.getParam('callBack');
    // here reuse question & answer list to build the dialog
    // .....
},

onDialogClick(component,event,helper){
    var callBack = component.get('v.callBack');
    callBack.call(dialogResult);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Developed this component, in [github](https://github.com/Chaos-Tech-Corp/Modal-Confirmation).

It creates a custom confirmation dialog, allows custom title, tagline and body, handles the Esc key press to close it and best of all: will call back to your confirmation function, so no need to duplicate code everywhere.

```
<c:modal_confirmation title="Modal Confirmation Box" 
                      tagline="This is a modal confirmation box" 
                      message="Are you sure you want to continue?" 
                      confirm="{!c.handleConfirm}"/>
```

Get to the code and tweak it for your needs, change the button labels, etc...

[image: modal dialog example]